# Yii controller method call from view button

Tags: javascript, php, yii, view, controller

I've been reading a lot about this but I can't find a proper solution for my issue.

In **Yii** framework, I need to execute a **controller** method after clicking into a **button** from a **view**. I tried to do this with Javascript but it's not working.
I don't need to change anything from the view, just execute the code into the controller. Just after controllers execution is done, I have to get the return variable to show some answer on the view.

Comment: What have you tried so far, please add your code. Did you try something with ajax?

Answer (score 2):

[AjaxButton in yii](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#ajaxButton-detail):

```
echo CHtml::ajaxButton('ButtonName',Yii::app()->createUrl('controller/action'),
                array(
                    'type'=>'POST',
                    'data'=> 'js:{"data1": val1, "data2": val2 }',                        
                    'success'=>'js:function(data){ alert(data); /* */}',
                    'update'=>'selectorNameToBeUpdated',           
                ),array('class'=>'someClass',));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
     onclick="callController();"
```

Use it using ajax, create a function and call it via javascript using onclick event.

```
 <script>
  function callController(){
   $.post("index.php?r=controllerName/functionName, function (data) {
  });

 }
 </script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but what's 'function(data){' for?

Do I get the return there?

Comment: whatever you echo in the function will be in the data variable..e.g. if you echo "called"; in the function, and if you alert(data); you will see called in the alert box :) .. @JuanMiguel mark it as answered if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got a solution making a mixture of your advices. Besides, I'm working on a third party project and the code is quite confusing, actually the controller wasn't in the right directory... Anyway, this is my solution:

On my view, call to my JavaScript function

```
onclick="myMethod(myVar");
```

then:

```
<script>
function myMethod(Var) {

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url:    "<? echo Yii::app()->createUrl('MyController/MyControllerMethod'); ?>",
    data:  {val: Var},
    success: function(msg){
        alert("Operation result: " + msg)
    },
    error: function(xhr){
        alert("failure"+xhr.readyState+this.url)
    }
});
}
</script>
```

In my controller, just did some operations and return with echo:

```
public function actionMyControllerMethod() {

   // some operations

   echo $result;
}
```